# When you leave input field, a function is triggered which change input background color

Tags: javascript, html

How can I do like, when my cursor leave input field, a function is triggered which change input background color.
I was trying to do like this, but did not work well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" onchange="changeColor()">

<script>
function changeColor() {
  const x = document.getElementById("name");
  x.style.background = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that you looking for `onfocusout` event.

```js
function changeColor(ev) {  
  if (ev.value.length > 0) {
    ev.style.background = "red";  
  }
}
```

```html
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name" onfocusout="changeColor(this)">
```

Comment: Thanks!! This seems good. But why if I type something, it works, when I select what I typed before, it does not work. Is it problem about browser

Comment: @CandyLee Because one was an onchange event and this one is a focusout event. I have updated my answer and changed your code a bit. Additionally I added an if condition that changes the huintergd and colour only if at least one character is written into the input.

Comment: That helps me a lot, thks.

Comment: @CandyLee You welcome! If you found it was helpful would be nice if you are accept this answer. If you found it good upvote it. Thanky you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
function changeColor(ev) {
  ev.target.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: When answering, it's recommended to share some context instead of just posting a snippet. [Check this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `blur` event to target specifically the lose of focus:

```
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="name">

<script>
const x = document.getElementById("name");

x.onblur = changeColor;

function changeColor() {
  x.style.background = "red";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would recommend  it to be used on `onblur` and `onmouseout` and `onfocusout`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen you mean `onblur`, right? :)

Comment: yeah, sorry, was side tracked lol

Answer (score 0):

Try the onmouseleave event listener.
onchange usually involved the value of the input field changing.

In CSS you have :focus selector to style based of if the input is focused or not